# Immersion and Submersion between Manifolds

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I am reading "An introduction to Manifolds" by Loring Tu. There they've first defined immersion and submersion between manifolds and then gave an example. In the last line of the example they've written **This example shows in particular that a submersion need not be onto.** And i am unable to understand that statement. For reference the following is the way they've defined immersion and submersion:
A $C^\infty$ map $F:N\to M$ is said to be an immersion at $p\in N$ if its differential $F_{*,p}:T_pN\to T_{F(p)M}$ is injective and a submersion at p if $F_{*,p}$ is surjective.We call F an immersion if it is an immersion at every $p\in N$ and a submersion if it is a submersion at every $p\in N$. I am attaching the screenshot of the example they've given and there i have highlighted the statement that i could not understand. My doubt is that surjective by definition means **onto** so how can a submersion need not be onto?[image: Screenshot of example]

Comment: what page is it on?

Comment: The map $i : U \to M$ is an inclusion map, where $U \subset M$ is open. So $i$ is injective but not onto, whereas $i_{*,p}$ is bijective for every $p \in U$.

Comment: The definition of submersion says that the DIFFERENTIAL is onto (not the map itself).

Comment: @HankIgoe it is at page no. 96 under section 8.8 of 2nd edition.

Comment: yeah both SiKucing and Nick are correct. the map $i$ itself need not be onto as submersion was defined as "the differential is onto".

Comment: @Nick Can you explain how $i_{*,p}$ is surjective? I mean since $i_{*,p}$ is the map $\iota_{*}:T_pU\rightarrow T_pM$ and  the domain and range of $i_{*,p}$ are different which means there are elements in $T_p M$ that have no preimage in $U$.

Comment: @Nick how do you know it's surjective? Please see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4017227/how-is-the-inclusion-map-both-an-immersion-and-submersion-between-manifolds)

Comment: @BCLC In the example of the inclusion map of an open subset $U \subset M$, if $p \in U$, then $T_pU = T_pM$, so the differential $i_*$ is the identity map on $T_pM$.

Comment: @Nick But $T_pU$ and $T_pM$ are not literally equal right? See the comments in the answer below as well as the link [i sent you](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4017227/how-is-the-inclusion-map-both-an-immersion-and-submersion-between-manifolds)

Comment: Sure, but they are isomorphic in an obvious way.

Answer (score 3):

If $\iota: U\hookrightarrow M$ denotes the inclusion, where $U\neq M$ is open in $M$, then $\iota_{*}:T_pM\rightarrow T_pM$ is both, injective and surjective. Hence $\iota$ is an immersion and a submersion. But $\iota$ clearly need not be surjective.

Comment: Can you explain if $\iota: U\hookrightarrow M$ denotes the inclusion **then why** automatically $\iota_{*}:T_pM\rightarrow T_pM$ is both injective and surjective?

Comment: Because $\iota_{*}$ is the identity map

Comment: Shouldn't $\iota_{*}:T_pM\rightarrow T_pM$ be $\iota_{*}:T_pU\rightarrow T_pM$? Since the domain of $\iota$ is restricted to only $U$.

Comment: And now when the domain and codomain of $\iota_{*}$ are not equal how can this be a identity map?

Comment: @JasonLiam $T_pU=T_pM$ for all $p\in U$.

Comment: Do we have a proof for $T_p U=T_p M$. For example $U$ is a subset of $M$ and how can the tangent space at all points $p\in M$ be equal to tangent space at the same point in $U$? Shouldn't this be $T_p U\simeq T_p M$ instead of the strict equality. You only considered for $p\in U$ but didn't considered the converse.

Comment: If $U$ is open in $M$ then $C_p^{\infty}(U)=C_p^{\infty}(M)$ for all $p\in U$.

Comment: Moe, are you sure you can that $T_pU$ and $T_pM$ are literally equal and not just isomorphic? Same with the set of germs $C_p^{\infty} U$ and $C_p^{\infty} M$. In the sense that they are literally equal, of course it's easy to say $\iota$ is immersion and submersion: The differential is the identity! See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4017227/how-is-the-inclusion-map-both-an-immersion-and-submersion-between-manifolds) please

Comment: If $C_{p}^{\infty}U=C_{p}^{\infty}M$ then $T_pU=T_pM$. Sure, if you want to be really technical and pedantic, then  the germs are canonically isomorphic and its common practice to not distinguish between them. But yes, if you assert that $C_{p}^{\infty}(U)$ and $C_{p}^{\infty}(M)$ are literally equal, then $T_pU$ and $T_pM$ must be literally equal for $p\in U$.

Comment: In particular, if $C_{p}^{\infty}(U)=C_{p}^{\infty}(M)$ then $T_pU=\{ v_p:C_{p}^{\infty}(U) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  $:$ $v_p$ linear and satisfies product rule $\}$ $=$ $\{ v_p:C_{p}^{\infty}(M) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ $:$ $v_p$ linear and satisfies product rule $\}$ $=T_pM$

Comment: oh thanks Moe, though i wasn't notified because you didn't tag me

Comment: what do you say to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4017329/how-is-the-algebra-c-p-inftyu-of-germs-of-c-infty-functions-in-u-a#comment8524952_4017863) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3269652/t-ps-subseteq-t-pm-are-tangent-spaces-of-submanifolds-subsets-and-not-embed) too in addition to [my answer in previous link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4017227/how-is-the-inclusion-map-both-an-immersion-and-submersion-between-manifolds) please.