# Tangent space to an open subset of a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm reading "Introduction to Manifolds" 2nd edition by Loring W. Tu and have a question.

Remark 8.2 of this book says that

"If $U$ is an open set containing $p$ in $M$, then the algebra $C_p^{\infty}(U)$ of germs of $C^{\infty}$ functions in $U$ at $p$ is the same as $C_p^{\infty}(M)$. Hence, $T_pU$ = $T_pM$."

But I can't understand this sentence. $C_p^{\infty}(U)$ is clearly contained in $C_p^{\infty}(M)$ but I don't know the other inclusion.

So I browsed "Introduction to Smooth Manifolds" by John M.Lee and found proposition 3.9 saying that

"Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with or without boundary, let $U \subset M$ be an open subset, and let $i:U{\hookrightarrow}M$ be an inclusion map. For every $p\in U$, the differential $di_p: T_pU {\hookrightarrow} T_pM$ is an isomorphism." followed by the sentences of proof of this proposition.

The key point of this proposition is same as Remark 8.2. of Tu's book in my thought.
And I think that Remark 8.2 of Tu's book is less rigorous. Am I right?

---

This is another question. Lee's book contains exercises that require to prove that real projective space is a manifold by showing it is second countable and Hausdorff. Is that short and obvious? Tu's book assign much more pages to prove that.

Comment: Your s3cond question should be asked separately. As for your first question, did you understand what germs are? The key is that every open subset of $U$ is also open in $M$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan Yes, they are equivalence classes of smooth functions that identify functions that coincide in a neighborhood of p. Anyway, I have found https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4017329/how-is-the-algebra-c-p-inftyu-of-germs-of-c-infty-functions-in-u-a?rq=1 this, which I couldn't find before. This would be the answer of my question :)

Comment: Yes, this is the same question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How is the Algebra $C_{p}^{\infty}(U)$ of germs of $C^\infty$ functions in $U$ at $p$ is the Same as $C_{p}^{\infty}(M)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4017329/how-is-the-algebra-c-p-inftyu-of-germs-of-c-infty-functions-in-u-a)